# Java HTML renderer with custom HTML tags view

Tags: java, html, swing, tags, jtextpane

I have task to implement HTML renderer. That's ok, i have used `javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument`.
Now i have to implement custom view for HTML tags:

1. `<u>` - wavy underline
2. `<b>` - usual bold style + text shadow

I've tried:

```
    pane = new JTextPane();
    pane.setEditable(false);
    add(new JScrollPane(pane));

    StyledEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit() {
      public Document createDefaultDocument() {
        HTMLDocument doc = new CustomHTMLDocument(getStyleSheet());
        StyleSheet sheet = doc.getStyleSheet();
        sheet.addRule("b {text-shadow: #6374AB 14px -6px 2px; }");
        return doc;
      }
    };
    pane.setEditorKit(kit);
```

But this doesn't work.
Can anybody help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this to add your own custom tag in the HTMLEditorKit
http://java-sl.com/custom_tag_html_kit.html

Answer (score 1):

Swing's HTML/CSS rendering is extremely basic.  I am not surprised that it supports neither of the 'wavy underline' nor 'text shadow'.